# How do I clean up cached partial images from a broken Docker pull?

Tags: caching, docker, pull

Docker 1.12.3-cs4
CentOS 7.2.1511

I have a lot of missing space on my machine (order of several gigs) due to a broken Docker pull.  By broken pull, I mean the machine datetime was out of synch, so midway during the pull it was generating an "authorization required" error.

All of the standard listing of images and containers, including showing dangling and all, etc, shows there are no images or containers locally.  Yet, that space is still occupied.  /v/l/d/devicemapper/devicemapper has 2 files, data and metadata, totaling 5g.  My entire /v/l/d is 7g.  This is with no images and containers.

I understand I could remove the entire docker structure and just start over.  But, if I had containers I needed to save, etc, that's not a practical solution, especially when sitting at almost full.  So.......is there a practical way to clean up the cache of a broken pull that wouldn't impact existing containers?

Hopefully this makes sense.  If not, please let me know how and where I can clarify.

Thank you!